# Python is not storing the user's input from tkinter's Entry widget into a variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a game where a user inputs their bet and betting amount on which "turtle" will take the shortest amount of time to reach the top of the screen. However, despite using StringVar() and .get() to store the user's responses, the responses just dont seem to be stored right. Instead of the user input being the variables' values, it is 0 and "" even though those aren't the user's input. However, when I deleted the turtle module code, the inputted values were set as the variables' values correctly for some reason

```
import turtle
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

Bank_account = 50



class turtle_s:

    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
        self.turt = turtle.Pen()
        self.turt.shape('turtle')
        self.turt.color(color)


red_turtle = turtle_s('red')
blue_turtle = turtle_s('blue')
yellow_turtle = turtle_s('yellow')

turtle_list = [red_turtle, blue_turtle, yellow_turtle]


## Turtle Game Setup
def turtle_stuff():

    turtle.screensize(canvwidth=500, canvheight=500)
    turtle.bgcolor('black')

    for color_turtle in turtle_list:

        if turtle_list.index(color_turtle) % 3 == 0:

            color_turtle.turt.penup()
            color_turtle.turt.setpos(-300, -250)
            color_turtle.turt.left(90)

        elif turtle_list.index(color_turtle) % 3 == 1:

            color_turtle.turt.penup()
            color_turtle.turt.setpos(300, -250)
            color_turtle.turt.left(90)

        else:

            color_turtle.turt.penup()
            color_turtle.turt.setpos(0, -250)
            color_turtle.turt.left(90)


    def turtle_move():

        global red_time_dif
        global blue_time_dif
        global yellow_time_dif

        for color_turtle in turtle_list:

            color_turtle.turt.speed(random.randrange(1, 5))

            if color_turtle == red_turtle:

                start = time.time()

                color_turtle.turt.goto(-300, 250)

                end = time.time()

                red_time_dif = end - start

                print("Red Turtle: {} seconds".format(round(red_time_dif, 5)))

            elif color_turtle == blue_turtle:

                start = time.time()

                color_turtle.turt.goto(300, 250)

                end = time.time()

                blue_time_dif = end - start

                print("Blue Turtle: {} seconds".format(round(blue_time_dif, 5)))


            else:

                start = time.time()

                color_turtle.turt.goto(0, 250)

                end = time.time()

                yellow_time_dif = end - start

                print("Yellow Turtle: {} seconds".format(round(yellow_time_dif, 5)))

    def result():

        global Bank_account
        global red_time_dif
        global blue_time_dif
        global yellow_time_dif
        global turtle_bet
        global bet_amount


        if red_time_dif < blue_time_dif and yellow_time_dif:

            if turtle_bet.lower() == "red":

                print("Red turtle wins!\nYou win {} coins! You now have {} coins in total!".format(str(bet_amount), Bank_account))
                Bank_account += int(bet_amount)

            else:

                print("Red turtle wins!\nYou lost {} coins! You now have {} coins in total!".format(str(bet_amount), Bank_account))
                Bank_account -= int(bet_amount)

        if blue_time_dif < red_time_dif and yellow_time_dif:

            if turtle_bet.lower() == "blue":

                print("Blue turtle wins!\nYou win {} coins! You now have {} coins in total!".format(str(bet_amount), Bank_account))
                Bank_account += int(bet_amount)

            else:

                print("Blue turtle wins!\nYou lost {} coins! You now have {} coins in total!".format(str(bet_amount), Bank_account))
                Bank_account -= int(bet_amount)

        if yellow_time_dif < red_time_dif and blue_time_dif:

            if turtle_bet.lower() == "yellow":

                print("Yellow turtle wins!\nYou win {} coins! You now have {} coins in total".format(str(bet_amount), Bank_account))
                Bank_account += int(bet_amount)

            else:

                print("Yellow turtle wins!\nYou lost {} coins! You now have {} coins in total".format(str(bet_amount), Bank_account))

    turtle_move()

    result()













def enter_input():
    global turtle_bet
    global bet_amount

    turtle_bet = user_turtle_bet.get()
    bet_amount = user_bet_amount.get()
    turtle_stuff() # trigger the turtle code






## Tkinter Entry Setup
tk = Tk()

user_turtle_bet = StringVar()
user_bet_amount = IntVar()

user_turtle_label = Label(tk, text="Turtle Bet", font=('Times', 13, 'bold'))
user_turtle_entry = Entry(tk, textvariable=user_turtle_bet, font=('Times', 13, 'normal'))

user_amount_label = Label(tk, text="Bet Amount", font=('Times', 13, 'bold'))
user_amount_entry = Entry(tk, textvariable=user_bet_amount, font=('Times', 13, 'normal'))

enter_button = Button(tk, text="ENTER", command=enter_input)

user_turtle_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
user_turtle_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
user_amount_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
user_amount_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
enter_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

tk.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is not stored in the `textvariable` but in your `Entry` variables. Don't use the `textvariable`, but directly get the input from the entry widgets. `turtle_bet = user_turtle_entry.get()` and `bet_amount = user_amount_entry.get()`. You can check aftwerwards if the input was correct with an if else statement for example and even print an error if the user used a wrong input (String or Int).

Then it worked just fine for me :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have multiple instances of `Tk()`.

Since `turtle` is based on `tkinter`, after the below lines:

```
red_turtle = turtle_s('red')
blue_turtle = turtle_s('blue')
yellow_turtle = turtle_s('yellow')
```

a *default instance of `Tk()`* is created implicitly because there is none.

Then `tk = Tk()` create another instance of `Tk()`.

To fix this, move `tk = Tk()` before the three lines.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter Entry Widget doesn't have a text variable But You can directly assign the value of the Entry box to a variable.

```
textBox = Entry(window)
textBox.pack()

textValue = textBox.get()
```